# Entity Framework setup issue

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

When I run my code

```
using (foodEntities db_Linq = new foodEntities())
{
    return db_Linq.Database.Exists();
    //return db_Linq.Foods.Any();
}
```

I keep getting this error in the `output` window.

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

What could be the issue? DB Credentials in web.config?

Other info:
I actually have 2 projects in my solution. One's a class library, the other MVC 4 web project.
Class library uses Entity Framework connection. Web project uses ADO connection string.
The above issue happens when web project calls the class library.
The code given above is from class library.

Comment: Have you inserted the connectionstring present in library to the web config ?

Comment: Can you just ignore this exception? What happens if you do?

Comment: Gerard, I am making a ajax request and getting a internal server error(500). Cant ignore.

Comment: Max, I have tried using the same connection string from `app.config`, but issue remains.

Comment: In your connectionstring using integrated security ? If yes check if application pool user can reach the database. Check also 32/64 bit library / application pool

Answer (score 0):

What version of the EF are you using? It seemed to me that you use EF6 and you have issues with the namespaces.

Please, check [Updating Applications to use EF6](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20Applications%20to%20use%20EF6) link. The main part for you is *"Update namespaces for any core EF types being used"*